# Anything similar in javascript to ruby's #{value} (string interpolation)

Tags: javascript, ruby

i am tired of writing this:

> string_needed="prefix....." + topic + "suffix...." + name + "testing";

i would think someone might have done something about this by now ;)

Comment: Better make a shortcut for it then, this syntax won't go anywhere for a while. ;) The best you could do is something like a `sprintf` function, but that won't make things any shorter.

Comment: See the top-rated answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: ECMAscript 6 has template strings... so yes, in the future you will be able to do \`string text ${expression} string text\`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## ES6 Update:

ES6 added template strings, which use backticks (`) instead of single or double quotes. In a template string, you can use the `${}` syntax to add expressions. Using your example, it would be:

```
string_needed = `prefix.....${topic}suffix....${name}testing`
```

## Original answer:

Sorry :(

I like to take advantage of Array.join:

```
["prefix ....", topic, "suffix....", name, "testing"].join("")
```

or use `String.concat`

```
String.concat("a", 2, "c")
```

or you could write your own concatenate function:

```
var concat = function(/* args */) {
    /*
     * Something involving a loop through arguments
     */
}
```

or use a 3rd-party `sprintf` function, such as http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Comment: +1 for Array.join. Fastest method of doing this that you'll find (it's also much faster than raw string concatenation).

Comment: @Reid may i suggest this? http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/09/14/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/ ;)

Comment: Was just gonna say... Despite this technique getting a lot of attention, Array#join is *not* faster than string concatenation in many cases.

Comment: also one of a problem with array join approach is that it is hard it translate if you care about i18n. It's much easier to translate string like "I played %s with %i people." than "I played ", " with " and " people.".

Comment: [`+` is faster than either join or concat](http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join). @Couto dead link.

Answer (score 10):

You could consider using [coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/#strings) to write the code (which has interpolation like Ruby ie #{foo}).

It 'compiles' down to javascript - so you will end up with javascript like what you've written, but without the need to write/maintain the +++ code you're tired of

I realize that asking you to consider another language is on the edge of being a valid answer or not but considering the way coffeescript works, and that one of your tags is Ruby, I'm hoping it'll pass.

Answer (score 7):

As a Javascript curiosity, you can implement something that basically does Ruby-like interpolation:

```
sub = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/#\{(.*?)\}/g,
    function(whole, expr) {
      return eval(expr)
    })
}

js> y = "world!"
world!
js> sub("Hello #{y}")
Hello world!
js> sub("1 + 1 = #{1 + 1}")
1 + 1 = 2
```

**Using it on anything but string literals is asking for trouble**, and it's probably quite slow anyways (although I haven't measured).  Just thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer: No javascript doesn't support string interpolation.

The only way is to implement it yourself or use a third party lib who does it for you.

**EDIT**

As Marcos added in comments theres a proposal for  ECMAScript 6 (Harmony), so we can have proper string interpolation:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and\nnot ${2 * a + b}.`);
// "Fifteen is 15 and
// not 20."
```

Please see more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

Comment: This has changed. There is now a better way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings  Bringing in 2015 to JS what many languages like Ruby and PHP have enjoyed already.

Neither this question nor its SO "duplicate" are allowing newer answers....so sad.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this hacky function to do this. Usage is as follows:

```
interpolate("#{gimme}, #{shelter}", {gimme:'hello', shelter:'world'})
// returns "hello, world"
```

And the implementation:

```
interpolate = function(formatString, data) {
    var i, len,
        formatChar,
        prevFormatChar,
        prevPrevFormatChar;
    var prop, startIndex = -1, endIndex = -1,
        finalString = '';
    for (i = 0, len = formatString.length; i<len; ++i) {
        formatChar = formatString[i];
        prevFormatChar = i===0 ? '\0' : formatString[i-1],
        prevPrevFormatChar =  i<2 ? '\0' : formatString[i-2];

        if (formatChar === '{' && prevFormatChar === '#' && prevPrevFormatChar !== '\\' ) {
            startIndex = i;
        } else if (formatChar === '}' && prevFormatChar !== '\\' && startIndex !== -1) {
            endIndex = i;
            finalString += data[formatString.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex)];
            startIndex = -1;
            endIndex = -1;
        } else if (startIndex === -1 && startIndex === -1){
            if ( (formatChar !== '\\' && formatChar !== '#') || ( (formatChar === '\\' || formatChar === '#') && prevFormatChar === '\\') ) {
                finalString += formatChar;
            }
        }
    }
    return finalString;
};
```